# Lavavel resource, when condition non-object error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, resources

I try to make conditional resource items but I get an error Trying to get property 'value' of non-object

```php
            'te' => $this->when($this->recup, $this->recup->test), // don't work
            'test' => $this->recup ? ($this->recup->test) : 'null', // works


 public function recup()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Animal::class);
    }
```

Why with when condition is not working ?
Thx

Comment: `when` condition should be like this `'te' => $this->when($this->recup==$this->recup->test)`

Comment: nope, this doesn't work

Comment: for test you may check like this `'te' => $this->when(1==1)`

Comment: actually the test is ```php $this->when($this->recup !== null,$this->recup->test) ``` but $his-recup-test show error of non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `optional()` method like so:

`'te' => $this->when($this->recup, optional($this->recup)->test)`